# How to trigger Angular to recompile a template from JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I understand that the solution will be non-ideal -- I'm working with legacy code and have many constraints.

On a page in my app, the user choose between one of several forms they want to fill out. When selected, we use JQuery to load the selected form into the DOM. In this newly loaded form, we need to use an angular directive, but angular doesn't know that anything has changed (since JQuery handled the state change), so it doesn't recompile the markup that contains our directive.

How can I let angular know that it needs to make another pass through the DOM?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Comment: I was in a similar situation, how to get a process to transition from jQuery to angular, I finally resorted to jQuery loading another url, and from there, letting angular (bootstrap) do it's thing, I couldn't find a programmatic way to transition on the fly from script to script - the other choice was to write all in one or the other, so the transition by url worked for me, all though your situation does not lend itself to that, based on your description, but if you think of a way to transition the page, that would allow you to use both frameworks

Comment: Also, take a look at $compile

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.apply()` will trigger a new check of the DOM.

If you use it with no check, it may fire an error inside angular.

You can use it, wrapped into a `$timeout()`, so that it will be triggered after a current digest (if there was)

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply();
});
```